# Does Fortify have a VS2017 plugin?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, fortify

When I install fortify, I see options only for VS2015 plugin or older. Just to be sure - is a VS2017 plugin available as of now, or no? My version is HPE_Security_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_16.20_windows_x64.exe, maybe there is a newer version, I don't know.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio 2017 Plugin is planned for the next release (17.20), which is coming out soon.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the plug in but in the visual studio gallery it says it supports visual studio 2017

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HPESecurityFortify.HPESecurityFortifyonDemandExtension-18282

Comment: That is the FoD plugin not for SCA.